# How to add other fields in my ASP.NET CV upload form

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms, email, runatserver

I've managed to successfully send an email with a CV/Resume attachment attached to it, however how do I add other fields (Full name and Comments) within the form to be displayed in the email.

I have the following code in my aspx.vb:

```
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.IO

Partial Class Default_VB
  Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    If FileUpload1.HasFile Then

  Dim toAddress As String = "email@address.com"
  Dim fromAddress As String = "email@anotheraddress.com"
  Dim mailServer As String = "smtp.1and1.com"

  Dim myMailMessage As MailMessage = New MailMessage()

  myMailMessage.To.Add(toAddress)
  myMailMessage.From = New MailAddress(fromAddress)
  myMailMessage.Subject = "Test Message"

  Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName)
  Dim myAttachment As New Attachment(FileUpload1.FileContent, fileName)
  myMailMessage.Attachments.Add(myAttachment)

  Dim mySmtpClient As New SmtpClient(mailServer)

  mySmtpClient.Send(myMailMessage)

End If

 End Sub
 End Class
```

And my HTML:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<label for="FullName">Full Name:</label> 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server"/> 

<label for="Comments">Comments:</label> 
<asp:TextBox ID="txtComments" runat="server"/>   

<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Send" /></div>
```

Comment: Please explain a bit more. Do u want to add fields on form for  (Full name and Comments) and that will be shown in email subject?

Comment: Hi @Syeda - I'm trying to get the fields Full Name and Comments to also appear in the same email that the CV/resume is sent on. Hope that helps. Thanks.

Comment: @Syeda at the moment, it just sends the uploaded CV, not the other two fields.... Full Name and Comments.

Comment: In email subject you want to add full name and comment?

Comment: @Syeda Sorry, not in the subject line, but in the actual body of the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case you can do like this,

```
myMailMessage.Body = txtName.Text+",\n"+txtComments.Text;
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I now get the following error: "Compiler Error Message: BC30037: Character is not valid." Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Provide the full name and comment that you are giving

Comment: I deleted the ; at the end of the line of code you sent me and it worked. I honestly cannot thank you enough. Very kind of you to help :-) Thank you.

Comment: I am glad than i can help :)